# Finding the size of file while typing

Tags: python, filesize

Is there any way in Python I can check the size of a particular file continuously while I am typing in that file but not saving the file?

Goal: My goal is to get the typing speed of the user in a particular project or a file. Any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: What are you using to type in the file?

Comment: Only if you communicate with the program you're typing into, otherwise no (without **MAJOR** memory hacking).

Comment: @cheniel Ohh. Is it editor dependent?

Comment: @KingJames It would be. Exactly what Cyphase is saying.

Comment: ohh. okay. Then I guess I have to scrap this idea! Anyway thanks a lot for clarification.

Comment: The problem is that the editor will not be writing to disk as you type - that would be very inefficient.  It will be writing to an in-memory buffer, and only write to disk when the buffer is full, or when you save.  Many editors will show you the size of the file as you type, `vi` and `vim` accept a CTRL+G to give some of that information.

Comment: Usually the file size will be the number of characters written into it, in bytes.

Comment: okay, I have updated the questions with my end goal of asking this query. @cheniel

Comment: You'd have to write the editor that the user is typing into yourself. You could mock something up using raw_input() just to have a proof of concept, then do the actual editor in Tkinter or something?

Comment: Many editors can be extended by plugins, so maybe you could write such a plugin or it may even exist already.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, typing speed and changing of file size are very different things. User can use copy/paste, so file size can grow very fast. But if you need to measure typing speed, there are at least two ways to do it:

- Sometimes it is possible to grab keyboard input and analyze name of current
  active program (may be you can even get name of current text file opened in text editor). So, if current program is editor, you will count
  number of key presses. To suggest something about it we need to know list of operating systems where you need this feature (may be you need `pyHook` or something like this).
- also sometimes it is possible to create extension for powerfull
  text editor (see [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Typing_Speed_Meter)). To suggest something about it we need to know list of text editors to be supported.